# HomePod alarm that streams a TuneIn station with Apple Music's new Voice Plan?

Tags: apple-music, homepod

HomePod and HomePod Mini support streaming radio stations on demand, without an Apple Music subscription. But streaming a radio station as an alarm requires a subscription. Could I use an Apple Music Voice Plan to set up a HomePod alarm that streams a TuneIn station?

I've checked Apple support docs and various online coverage of the Voice Plan, but didn't see a clear answer. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer appears to be no. After activating a trial with "Hey Siri, start Apple Music Voice", I tried to choose media for a HomePod Mini (15.2) alarm in the iOS Home app (15.2), and was told "Adding audio to an alarm requires that you have an active Apple Music membership". Following the "Get Apple Music" option only showed the full subscription as an option.

Based on this I think Apple requires a full subscription to choose media for an alarm. Possibly a trial doesn't count, but that seems less likely.